# Puppet report processor sends the same @host to Sentry for all reports

Tags: puppet

I want to send all `err` logs from all my puppet nodes to Sentry - the logs are successfully sent to the master via the `report = true` option.

Versions used:

- puppet: `7.10.0`
- sentry-ruby: `5.3.0`

Looking on my master server, I can see the reports under the `/opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver/reports/host_fqdn` directory and a quick inspect into a random `.yaml` file confirms that the `host` is set correctly:

```
--- !ruby/object:Puppet::Transaction::Report
host: host_1_fqdn
time: X
configuration_version: Y
transaction_uuid: Z
report_format: 12
logs: ...
```

As far as I understood, you can define a [custom reports processor](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6/reporting_write_processors.html) and you can access the deserialized yaml reports from the `Puppet::Transaction::Report` object inside the `process` method, by using `self`. Hence, I would expect to get the same host name in my processor, as it is in the reports file by doing the following:

```
if self.respond_to?(:host)
    @host = self.host
end
```

Now, for the previous report I gave as an example, I expect the `@host` variable to store the `host_1_fqdn` value. With this in mind, I continue with sending some data from the report to Sentry via:

```
self.logs.each do |log|
  if log.level.to_s == 'err'
    Sentry.capture_message(log.message +  ":", {
      :tags => {
        'server_name' => @host
      },
    })
  end
end
```

Looking into Sentry, I see that all my events are received, but all of them have the `server_name` tag with the same value, i.e. the hostname of the puppet master, instead of having `host_X_fqdn`.

Tried to look into lots of places into the upstream puppet [repo](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/main/lib/puppet/transaction/report.rb), but didn't find any hints of what could be wrong with my processor. To me it seems clearly that this is not Sentry-related at all, but I tried to provide the whole context, maybe my intuition is wrong.

Comment: What if you use `self.host` directly instead of assigning it to `@host`?  I think it's safe to assume that the reports will all carry that property, and if it turns out that some don't then that might itself explain your issue.

Comment: Was delayed a bit, tried your suggestion, but it didn't work. I managed to solve my tagging issues by using a different tag name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried first to update my reports processor as John suggested, but it didn't work. Looking closer into the Sentry Ruby [documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/ruby/enriching-events/tags/), I found out that it is not recommended to override the default tags.

> Some tags are automatically set by Sentry. We strongly recommend against overwriting those tags. Instead, name your tags with your organization's nomenclature.

Hence, I firstly updated my `sentry-ruby` gem to `5.5.0` via `puppetserver gem` and then removed the `server_name` tag from the code. Instead, I've defined a new one, named `client_name`, with exactly the same value, i.e. `self.host`, within the global scope.

```
Sentry.set_tags(
  'client_name': self.host,
  ...other tags
)
```

Now all of my events have both tags, `server_name` (which defaults to the puppet server name) and the `client_name` (which evaluates to the name of the affected puppet node).